# Ejecutar script python en Flask

Tags: python, flask

¿Cómo puedo ejecutar un script en flask?
Por ejemplo, mi sciprt recibe un número y devuelve el número aumentado en 10.
En local por supuesto que funciona, pero al subirlo a Flask, no se como hacerlo correctamente.
Lo que intenté fue:
Crear un formulario HTMl en la carpeta "templates" donde solo puse un input para recibir la variable y un submit, identificando la variable con `name`, y en actión puse el archivo `script.py` que es donde está el script, este archivo tambien lo puse en la carpeta "templates". 
Al hacer clic en `submit` si me lleva al archivo script.py, pero se imprime el código en texto plano, no se ejecuta el código.
¿Cómo debo hacer para que me reciba datos por un formulario, pasen por un algoritmo o script y me devuelva en un template HTML lo que devuelva el script? 
No encontré información relacionada en Google, tal vez es una pregunta facil, pero no logro resolverlo.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puede añadir ejemplos de código tiene? Actión debe ser un URI que puede aceptar petición (GET o POST?). Es impossible para responder sin saber contexto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logré resolverlo no de la mejor manera, peor suficiente para mis necesidades del proyecto.
Yo miraba que en tutoriales diversos, usaban objetos para los formularios, pero el mio no era un formulario de login ni ninguna información delicada. Solo usé el formulario de HTML, usé el método POST hacia otra ruta, en la ruta objetivo (en el main.py) le agregué todo mi script (tal vez no sea una buena práctica, pero me sirve), agregué las variables junto al template renderizado y ahí pude manipular las variables que obtuve como resultado a mi conveniencia.

Comment: He visto que pudiste solucionar tu problema. Pero a veces para que se pueda ayudarte en este tipo de situaciones es mejor que compartas una parte de tu código para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte, tienes que contextualizar tu problema para que así los demás puedan tratar de ayudar, un saludo amigo.